# Can't find the option to run Python file in web mode in Aptana studio 3

Tags: python, aptana3

I am using `Aptana studio 3` for `Python`. I created one `demo.py` file and typed some `print` statement. I tried to run this file with `run as` option but there was no sub options to run this file.

[image]

I have one doubt here whether the python interpreter is configured or not. Please help me to configure the `python interpreter` and run this file successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out location of your Python interpreter with command `which python` in your terminal. I am not using Aptana myself, but after invoking mentioned command, you should set Python's path somewhere in Aptana's settings. If you are using virtual environment, be sure that you invoke `which python` command **after** activating virtual env.

Maybe [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233740/configure-python-2-7-3-interpreter-in-aptana-studio) can instruct you further.